# How to play a list of (online) video segments as a whole video for Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to play a list of videos using a player framework. When I play the first video, I need the second video to start loading in a different thread while the first is still playing, this way when the first video ends, the second video can start playing immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

You can play media files on a Windows Phone using the [MediaPlayerLauncher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher(v=vs.105).aspx)  , or for a more customized experience, you can use the  [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.105).aspx)  class.

For more Reference  [Windows Phone Streaming Media](http://phonesm.codeplex.com/)  Project would be Useful to You and this too [How to play or stream a video file for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769551(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: I don't think that's what he needs. He already knows how to play a video, what he wants is to play a list of videos, in which each time a video is playing, the following video is already loading in a background thread

Comment: **Yes** @Florian.C **I want the same**